# Multi-index slicing (involving a time series / date range) does not work with DataFrame but does for Series

Tags: python, pandas

Slicing a multi-index DataFrame for a date range does not appear to work (dataframe is returned un-sliced), while performing the same operation for a multi-indexed Series does.

For example:

```
# Create a multi-indexed DataFrame with time series as 'inner' index
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-05')], names=['id', 'date'])
cols = ['colA', 'colB']
example_df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(30).reshape(15, 2), idx, cols)
```

example_df looks like:

```
                colA    colB
id  date        
id1 2019-01-01  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-02  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-03  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-04  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-05  1.0     1.0
id2 2019-01-01  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-02  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-03  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-04  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-05  1.0     1.0
id3 2019-01-01  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-02  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-03  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-04  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-05  1.0     1.0
```

Attempting to slice the inner 'date' index level, simply yields the DataFrame above unchanged.

```
# Get all records for 3rd January 2019 onward, for all ids
idx = pd.IndexSlice
example_df.loc[idx[:, '2019-01-3':]] # yields example_df unchanged
```

The desired result is:

```
                colA    colB
id  date        
id1 2019-01-03  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-04  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-05  1.0     1.0
id2 2019-01-03  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-04  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-05  1.0     1.0
id3 2019-01-03  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-04  1.0     1.0
    2019-01-05  1.0     1.0
```

Strangely, slicing a Series yields the expected result

```
# Perform same slice but just for colA
example_df.colA.loc[idx[:, '2019-01-3':]]
```

This yields the expected result

```
id   date      
id1  2019-01-03    1.0
     2019-01-04    1.0
     2019-01-05    1.0
id2  2019-01-03    1.0
     2019-01-04    1.0
     2019-01-05    1.0
id3  2019-01-03    1.0
     2019-01-04    1.0
     2019-01-05    1.0
```

I am on pandas 0.23.1.

Appreciate any input into how to get a the slice working for the DataFrame version. I know I can achieve the same result with a boolean mask over the inner date index i.e.

```
from datetime import datetime
inner_mask = example_df.index.get_level_values(1) >= datetime(2019, 1, 3)
example_df[inner_mask]
```

... but I'm keen to understand why this slicing method doesn't work (especially when it does work for the Series version). Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need specify column `colA` in second position in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print(example_df.loc[idx[:, '2019-01-3':], 'colA'])
id   date      
id1  2019-01-03    1.0
     2019-01-04    1.0
     2019-01-05    1.0
id2  2019-01-03    1.0
     2019-01-04    1.0
     2019-01-05    1.0
id3  2019-01-03    1.0
     2019-01-04    1.0
     2019-01-05    1.0
Name: colA, dtype: float64
```

If want onle column `DataFrame` use one element list:

```
print(example_df.loc[idx[:, '2019-01-3':], ['colA']])
                colA
id  date            
id1 2019-01-03   1.0
    2019-01-04   1.0
    2019-01-05   1.0
id2 2019-01-03   1.0
    2019-01-04   1.0
    2019-01-05   1.0
id3 2019-01-03   1.0
    2019-01-04   1.0
    2019-01-05   1.0
```

Same principe with boolean mask:

```
print(example_df.loc[inner_mask, 'colA'])
id   date      
id1  2019-01-03    1.0
     2019-01-04    1.0
     2019-01-05    1.0
id2  2019-01-03    1.0
     2019-01-04    1.0
     2019-01-05    1.0
id3  2019-01-03    1.0
     2019-01-04    1.0
     2019-01-05    1.0
Name: colA, dtype: float64

print(example_df.loc[inner_mask, ['colA']])
                colA
id  date            
id1 2019-01-03   1.0
    2019-01-04   1.0
    2019-01-05   1.0
id2 2019-01-03   1.0
    2019-01-04   1.0
    2019-01-05   1.0
id3 2019-01-03   1.0
    2019-01-04   1.0
    2019-01-05   1.0
```

For slice all column use `:`:

```
print(example_df.loc[idx[:, '2019-01-3':], :])
                colA  colB
id  date                  
id1 2019-01-03   1.0   1.0
    2019-01-04   1.0   1.0
    2019-01-05   1.0   1.0
id2 2019-01-03   1.0   1.0
    2019-01-04   1.0   1.0
    2019-01-05   1.0   1.0
id3 2019-01-03   1.0   1.0
    2019-01-04   1.0   1.0
    2019-01-05   1.0   1.0
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. Using `example_df.loc[idx[:, '2019-01-3':], ]` returns all the columns (which is what I desired). I'm wondering why we need to effectively specify `None` to the second position of `DataFrame.loc`, to return all the columns?

Comment: Better is use `:`  for all columns - `example_df.loc[idx[:, '2019-01-3':], :]`